# How to add list entries to a ListView in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add items of list of images to ListView in WPF like this:

**CS**

```
for (int i = 0; i < filtered_thumbnails.Count; i++)
{ 
    Image tmp = new Image();
    tmp = filtered_thumbnails.ElementAt(i);
    filtered_thumbnails.RemoveAt(i);  
    SlideTransitionsList.Items.Add(tmp);                    
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<ListView Background ="LightGray" Name="SlideTransitionsList" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.RowSpan="25" SelectionChanged="SlideTransitionsList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>

</ListView>
```

But I keep getting an error saying that it can't add elements because they are already child elements of other parent. So I tried to remove the item from the list prior to adding it to the ListView, but it still gives the same error. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why can't you bind the `filtered_thumbnails` list like the following :

```
SlideTransitionsList.ItemsSource=filtered_thumbnails;
```

If you iterate the `filtered_thumbnails` and assign each element seperately, during the first iteration the the image source is assigned to the collection, so in the second iteration, the item source is not empty(it having the first assigned element) so it doesn't allow to change. but you can assign a List as `ItemSource` to a list as mentioned above.

In your updates `ListView` defenition is missing, so i suggest you to define Like the following:

```
<ListView name="filtered_thumbnails" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView .ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView .ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I just tried, but I get the following: "Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual."

Comment: could you please post your xamal code? or include it in question?

Comment: sorry, I omitted the definition while copy-paste. please see the updated code. it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the databinding described in the other solution change your code to.

Otherwise omit the `ItemsSource={Binding}` of the following example

```
<ListView Background ="LightGray" Name="SlideTransitionsList" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.RowSpan="25" SelectionChanged="SlideTransitionsList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I did it, and it doesn't throw an error anymore, but I don't see any images shown in ListView